# How to put a datetime range to Elasticsearch Marvel URL

Tags: datetime, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-marvel

The Elasticsearch Marvel dashboard allows me to select a custom datetime range to display. But I wonder how to copy the URL to share with other people that includes my selected datetime range? Its default URL looks like:

```
http://<domain>:9200/_plugin/marvel/kibana/index.html#/dashboard/file/marvel.overview.json
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to go into these steps

- Dashboard Settings (top-right button)
- Select Control Tab
- Tick the "Allow Sharing" option, choose TTL on link if needed

Then you just need to select your time-period, and you will see on top a new button has appeared, its Export button. It will generate a shareable link.